# Can anyone provide me mapping of hadoop file shell commands to java classes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

am new to Hadoop and am working on Java API to manage files in HDFS and am looking for mapping(kind of) of hadoop file shell commands to java classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this mapping info?

Java class for each shell command:

```
factory.addClass(Merge.class, "-getmerge");
factory.addClass(Cp.class, "-cp");
factory.addClass(CopyFromLocal.class, "-copyFromLocal");
factory.addClass(CopyToLocal.class, "-copyToLocal");
factory.addClass(Get.class, "-get");
factory.addClass(Put.class, "-put");
factory.addClass(AppendToFile.class, "-appendToFile");
```

Comment: Yes, can you provide me java class name for this code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CopyCommands

```
class CopyCommands {  
  public static void registerCommands(CommandFactory factory) {
    factory.addClass(Merge.class, "-getmerge");
    factory.addClass(Cp.class, "-cp");
    factory.addClass(CopyFromLocal.class, "-copyFromLocal");
    factory.addClass(CopyToLocal.class, "-copyToLocal");
    factory.addClass(Get.class, "-get");
    factory.addClass(Put.class, "-put");
    factory.addClass(AppendToFile.class, "-appendToFile");
  }
```